# Not able to access RDS in my spring boot application inside docker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, amazon-rds

I wanted to dockerize my spring boot application. I used

```
docker build -t <Name> .
```

to build my project and then try to run it. But my spring boot application gives Communication link failure and is not able to connect to the rds database. I have setup database url correctly in properties file and my application is inside same VPC as the RDS. My docker file is:

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_TOOL_CHAIN
COPY pom.xml /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp/
RUN mvn verify clean --fail-never
COPY src /tmp/src/
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM tomcat:8.0.51-jre8-alpine
COPY --from=MAVEN_TOOL_CHAIN /tmp/target/<ProjectName>.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/<ProjectName>.war
COPY ./conf/* $CATALINA_HOME/conf/
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Stack trace of the error im getting is below:

```
2019-03-14 14:17:03.400  WARN 1 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01

2019-03-14 14:17:03.400 ERROR 1 --- [pool-3-thread-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2019-03-14 14:17:03.400  INFO 1 --- [pool-3-thread-1] c.d.c.s.c.CampaignAnalyticsService       : error in updating analytics Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
2019-03-14 14:17:03.400  INFO 1 --- [pool-3-thread-1] c.d.c.s.c.CampaignAnalyticsService       : [543, Send, Announcement, -, Sukhna:, Run, for, fun]
2019-03-14 14:17:03.401  INFO 1 --- [pool-3-thread-1] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-03-14 14:17:04.402 ERROR 1 --- [pool-3-thread-1] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I use the following command to run my image :

```
docker run -p 8081:8000 <Name>
```

Comment: "I have setup database url correctly" are you sure? Please share the way it is used (you don't have to include the URL itself) And why are you exposing "-p 3306:3306" to your container?

Comment: Exposing port was just a try to solve the actual problem. i have updated the question. Also, the project was running on the same server with just the built war file pasted in tomcat of the server directly without docker. That's why i told database url is correct.My db url in application.properties is jdbc:mysql://<RdsUrl>:3306/<DBName>

Comment: I think you should not specify a port when targeting RDS.

Comment: It is working properly outside docker.

Comment: Hi, am facing the same issue, were u able to find a solution